# Persisting Blobs using Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Although I know there is already a Blob service for Appengine, I want to experiment on storing big blobs within the datastore.

Basically I am trying to persist this object using Objectify:

[BigBlob.java](https://github.com/honzasterba/bigblobae/blob/master/src/org/honzasterba/bigblobae/BigBlob.java)

[BigBlobFragments.java](https://github.com/honzasterba/bigblobae/blob/master/src/org/honzasterba/bigblobae/BigBlobFragment.java)

However, appengine is complaining that: "`BigBlobFragment is not a supported property type`"

For the BigBlob type I created a DAO class with CRUD operation and registed the type like this:

```
static {
    ObjectifyService.register(BigBlob.class);
    //ObjectifyService.register(BigBlobFragment.class);
}

protected BigblobDaoImpl() {
    super(BigBlob.class);
}
```

I actually also have tried registering BigBlobFragment.

Hopefully someone can share some ideas on how to actually persist Big blobs and fragments using Objectify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used Blobs myself but I noticed you have `@PersistenceCapable` above your entities... that should be @Entity.

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
```

Then you should be able to register your entity with Objectify.

```
ObjectifyService.register(BigBlob.class);
```

Comment: I mean, I think the problem is with the underlying field class of BigBlog which is BigBlobFragment

Comment: @xybrek I see you have a Persistent annotation for the BigBlobFragment member in BigBlob. You need Embed annotation(for ofy4) or Embedded (for ofy3)

Comment: You mean the: javax.persistence.Embedded; not the  javax.jdo.annotations.Embedded; right?

Comment: Yes for objectify 3; objectify 4 has its own Embed annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register both the BigBlob and the BigBlobFragment and replace all of your JDO annotations with Objectify annotations (assuming you are using ofy4. You might also want to consider embedding the BigBlobFragment object inside of the BigBlob for performance using @Embed.